# How can I avoid reseting inputs in a form in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with many entries which the user should complete and then submit. With these inputs it would be done some calculations and then a result will be presented. When clicking on the submit button, all these inputs are erased BUT I want to maintain the inputs introduced by the user in order that  if he/she wants to recalculate (e.g. changing only one value or some), he/she can do it instead of introducing again all the data.

This is my form:

```
<div >  
  <div class="mod1_boxed">
    <strong>Jahres</strong><a id="dialog-1" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
      <%= form_tag( '/calculation/index', post: true ) do %>

          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module1", nil, placeholder: "3500", id: "user_entry", size: 10 %></br>

          <strong>PV-Große  </strong><a id="dialog-2" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module2", nil, placeholder: "5", id: "user_entry_2" %></br>

          <strong>Strompreis  </strong><a id="dialog-3" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module3", nil, placeholder: "24.5", id: "user_entry_3" %></br>

          <strong>Strom </strong><a id="dialog-4" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module4", nil, placeholder: "2.5", id: "user_entry_4" %></br>

          <strong>Ertrag  </strong><a id="dialog-5" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module5", nil, placeholder: "950", id: "user_entry_5" %></br>

          <strong>Degression der PV-Anlage </strong><a id="dialog-6" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module6", nil, placeholder: "0.5", id: "user_entry_6" %></br>

          <strong>PV-Anlagepreis</strong><a id="dialog-7" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module7", nil, placeholder: "1600", id: "user_entry_7" %></br>

          <strong>Einspeisevergütung </strong><a id="dialog-8" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module8", nil, placeholder: "12", id: "user_entry_8" %></br>

          <strong> Kfw-Förderung ? </strong><a id="dialog-9" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module9", nil, placeholder: "ja", id: "user_entry_9" %></br>

          <%= submit_tag "submit",  class: "send_button_1" %>

      <%end%>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I don't know it this is possible with Rails or it should be done with JQuery.

How would you do it? thxs. in advance.

Comment: When you clicked on submit button then it goes to controller for calculations or it is done via Javascript?

Comment: If you set value at `params[:name_of_your_field]` instead of `nil`, that don't do the trick ?

Comment: Well, I got first the inputs in Javascript and then I send them to my API (controller) and then back to Javascript. (inputs->javascript->API->javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module3", params["user_entry_module3"] || "", placeholder: "24.5", id: "user_entry_3" %>
```

and from the controller pass the `params` when recalculation needed.
Do it for all the `text_field_tag`

Comment: Sir, this is what I was looking for. Like.